# Окончание "-у" или "-а"?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

Как правильнее сказать/написать: "с разбега" или "с разбегу"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорощо бы всю фразу посмотреть.
Но если используется в значении наречия (он прыгнул с разбег[...]), то обе формы одинаково допустимы.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще в словарях пишут, что "С разбега" - с окончанием "а" употребляется в том случае, если это существительное или в разговорной речи!
С окончанием же "у" в речи употребляются наречия!

Comment: Уважаемая Вероника, Вы не могли бы при отсылке на словари приводить хотя бы один, подтверждающий Вашу версию?


РАЗБЕГ -а; м.  
1.  
к Разбежаться - разбегаться Р. перед прыжком. Взять р. (также:
достичь быстроты в работе, в каких-л. действиях).  
2.  
Длина пути, проходимого по земле до момента взлёта. Р. самолёта < *С разбега; с разбегу, в зн. нареч.*  
Разбежавшись, набрав большую скорость в беге.  
Кузекцов на gramota.ru
(Курсив мой, b-s)